# Firebase login with a service account

Tags: firebase, kotlin, https, firebase-authentication

I'm using `"com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0"` to upload files to Firebase Storage with my Kotlin app. But recently I found, Gradle can't build a correct .jar because of this dependency (runtime `Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt`). So, I'm trying to move to REST and HTTPS but can't make a proper auth nor upload with a service account JSON file (I need a silent auth). So, how can I do such things like these methods?

```
    val options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(FileInputStream("./${KEY_FILENAME}")))
        .setDatabaseUrl(URL).setStorageBucket(BUCKET_URL).build()

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)


    val bucket = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket()
    val blob = bucket.create("$dir/${file.name}", FileInputStream(file))
    return blob?.size
```

For HTTPS I tried this:

```
val serviceJsonStr = File("firebase.json").readText()
val serviceJson = Json.decodeFromString(FirebaseKey.serializer(), serviceJsonStr)

val url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
val headers = mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/json")

val body = OAuthRequestBody(
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    serviceJson
)

val response = ktor.post(url, headers, body)
```

But got `"Invalid value (assertion), Starting an object on a scalar field"`